# Get date in different format in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, date

I need to get the date which could be in 3 possible format.

1. 11/20/2012
2. 11.20.2012
3. 11-20-2012

How could I achieve this in Perl. I'm trying RegEx to get what I want. Here's my code.

```
my @dates = ("Mon 11/20/2012","2012.11.20","20-11-2012"); #array values may vary in every run 
foreach my $date (@dates){
    $date =~ /[-.\/\d+]/g;
    print "Date: $date \n";
}
```

I want the output to be. (code above doesn't print anything)

```
Date: 11/20/2012
Date: 2012.11.20
Date: 20-11-2012
```

Where am I wrong? Please Help. Thanks

Note: I want to achieve this without using any CPAN module as much as possible. I know there are a lot of CPAN modules that could provide what I want.

Comment: There is no (valid) reason not to use modules. There's also core modules that handle time.

Comment: @TLP It is a limitation on my side. I can't install a module on a cygwin Perl since I don't own the permission. It would take some months/years to repackage the cygwin Perl. I just want the script to be available as soon as possible. It is really just a complication on my side.

Comment: Your code works as expected!! Whats the problem you faced?

Comment: Have to agree with @KrishnachandraSharma the code does output close to what you want. Though only because it does not change your array in any way shape or form.

Comment: Yeah right, it works as expected. My bad, I forgot to print the dates on the actual code.

Comment: Even if you cannot install a module in the usual way, you may be able to use local::lib to install them.  Failing that, you can look at the source of one of these modules to see how they solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code almost produces what you want. I assume your input is a bit more complicated, or you have posted code that you are not actually running.

Either way, the problem is this

```
$date =~ /[-.\/\d+]/g;
```

First off, your plus multiplier is inside the character class: It should be after it. Second, it is just a pattern match, you need to use it in list context, and store its return value:

```
my ($match) = $date =~ /[-.\/\d]+/g;
print "Date: $match\n";
```

Then it will return the first of the strings found that contains one or more of dash, period, slash or a number. Be aware that it will match other things as well, as it is a rather unstrict regex.

Why does it work? Because a pattern match in list context returns a list of the matches when the global `/g` modifier is used.

Comment: Why is it with putting the () in $match doesn't print the date, it only print 1? Otherwise, it works. :D

Comment: The application of a regex match `m//` to a string returns different things depending on the context. In scalar context, it returns 1 or the empty string. In list context - if the `/g` modifier is used - it returns a list of the matches. Context is determined by the left hand side arguments. `$match` is a scalar, `($match)` is a list of 1 scalar. You can also use parentheses `()` to capture strings, which will then be returned.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the use of [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) module, which has a rich set of funcionality. Think not only in parsing strings, but also in checking the date is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Why not search for the formats one at a time?

```
=~ m!(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}|\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}|\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})!
```

should do the trick. Other than that, there's a module dealing with dates called [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime).

Answer (score 1):

Try matching the formats in turn. The regex below matches any of your permitted separators (`/`, `.`, or `-`) and then requires the same separator via backreference (`\2` or `\3`). Otherwise, you have three possible separators times two possible positions for the year to make *six* alternatives in your pattern.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#array values may vary in every run
my @dates = ("Mon 11/20/2012","2012.11.20","20-11-2012");

my $date_pattern = qr<
  \b  # begin on word boundary
  (
    (?:           [0-9][0-9] ([-/.]) [0-9][0-9] \2 [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
  | (?: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ([-/.]) [0-9][0-9] \3 [0-9][0-9])
  )
  \b  # end on word boundary
>x;

foreach my $date (@dates) {
  if (my($match) = $date =~ /$date_pattern/) {
    print "Date: $match\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 11/20/2012
Date: 2012.11.20
Date: 20-11-2012
```

On my first try at the code above, I had `\2` in the YYYY-MM-DD alternative where I should have had `\3`, which failed to match. To spare us counting parentheses, [version 5.10.0 added named capture buffers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Named-Capture-Buffers).

> - **Named Capture Buffers**
>
> It is now possible to name capturing parenthesis in a pattern and refer to the captured contents by name. The naming syntax is `(?<NAME>....)`. It's possible to backreference to a named buffer with the `\k<NAME>` syntax. In code, the new magical hashes `%+` and `%-` can be used to access the contents of the capture buffers.

Using this handy feature, the code above becomes

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use 5.10.0;  # named capture buffers

use strict;
use warnings;

#array values may vary in every run
my @dates = ("Mon 11/20/2012","2012.11.20","20-11-2012");

my $date_pattern = qr!
  \b  # begin on word boundary
  (?<date>
    (?:           [0-9][0-9] (?<sep>[-/.]) [0-9][0-9] \k{sep} [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
  | (?: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] (?<sep>[-/.]) [0-9][0-9] \k{sep} [0-9][0-9])
  )
  \b  # end on word boundary
!x;

foreach my $date (@dates) {
  if ($date =~ /$date_pattern/) {
    print "Date: $+{date}\n";
  }
}
```

and produces the same output.

The code above still contains a lot of repetition. Using the [`(DEFINE)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28DEFINE%29) special case combined with named captures, we can make the pattern much nicer.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use 5.10.0;

use strict;
use warnings;

#array values may vary in every run
my @dates = ("Mon 11/20/2012","2012.11.20","20-11-2012");

my $date_pattern = qr!
  \b (?<date> (?&YMD) | (?&DMY)) \b

  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<SEP>  [-/.])
    (?<YYYY> [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
    (?<MM>   [0-9][0-9])
    (?<DD>   [0-9][0-9])
    (?<YMD>  (?&YYYY) (?<sep>(?&SEP)) (?&MM) \k<sep> (?&DD))
    (?<DMY>  (?&DD)   (?<sep>(?&SEP)) (?&MM) \k<sep> (?&YYYY))
  )
!x;

foreach my $date (@dates) {
  if ($date =~ /$date_pattern/) {
    print "Date: $+{date}\n";
  }
}
```

Yes, the subpattern named DMY also matches dates int MDY form. For now it suffices, and [you ain’t gonna need it](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt).